# how to set initialRouteName dynamically using AsyncStorage in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I set initialRouteName "HomeScreen". And I want to see "HomeScreen" only once after installing the app. After that, every time when I will run the app it should render the "NewWallet" screen as my initialRouteName. how can I do it? I see some previous Questions and answer as well on this platform. But I don't get it!

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
  }} initialRouteName={"HomeScreen"} >
 
   <Stack.Screen
      name="HomeScreen"
      component={HomeScreen}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="NewWallet"
      component={NewWallet}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>

</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic rendering for this as described [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#switch-navigator) and in detail [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow).

If app is not opened first time it won't initialize **HomeScreen** so default screen would be **NewWallet**.

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
  }} >
 
   {isFirstTime && <Stack.Screen
      name="HomeScreen"
      component={HomeScreen}
    />}
    <Stack.Screen
      name="NewWallet"
      component={NewWallet}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>

</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: After Doing this every time the "HomeScreen"  appairs for a bit time then it shows the "NewWallet" screen. why it shows HomeScreen?? @Ashutosh

Comment: you're checking isFirstTime from **AsyncStorage** which is Async operation and takes a little time that's why. You can instead show splash screen or return null for this component till this info is retrieved.